# send mail on update task in odoo project management tool?

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-9

[image]Send mail when updates task in a project management tool or update the description of task that time I need to send email.

Comment: Why dont you provide more information, what have you tried which didnt work so someone can help you out.

Comment: i try to setup python code in project.py file but i don't know what code and how to setup

Comment: for mail setup try this link http://webkul.com/blog/odoo-mail-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved this one functionality:

Put the One button in this task Form view "Send Mail Info Of Pad" and when user update the paid then after click this button then after send the mail the followers of this task or any other user send the mail.

Comment: see screen shot save button already there when click on that button i want to send mail to follower

Comment: so you can overwrite the write () of the project.task and send mail to your followers.

Comment: i give you remote access can you see this or ping me on jaydipk@ociustechnologies.com